# How to get Soap Fault details elements in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, soap, soapfault

I try to cath a SOAP exception from ASMX Websirvice in my ASP.NET Core API.

The legacy ASMX Webservice throw a SOAP Exception like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An order must be specified
   at legacyNamespace.Common.WebServiceBase.CheckUserPermissionsForProject(String projectId)
   at legacyNamespace.CustomerApp.Defect.Defect.AcceptDefect(AcceptDefectModel defect)</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <errorCode>400</errorCode>
                <message>An order must be specified</message>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I'm trying to catch and process this exception in my ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API:

```
try
{
   // call the asmx service
}
catch (FaultException ex)
{
   var fault = ex.CreateMessageFault();
   if (fault.HasDetail)
   {
      var faultDetails = fault.GetDetail<XmlElement>();
      var test = faultDetails.InnerText;
   }
   ...
}
```

And the `test` var contains only the errorCode "400" and nothing more. `faultDetails` ChildNodes are empty.
If I try to call `GetDetail<XmlNode>()` than I got a serialization exception.
How can I get all detail elements?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after a few tries, I found a simple solution. You just need to add an additional node into the `detail` node. And then you will get it as an XMLElement with ChildNodes.

Than you can get it out:

```
var faultDetails = fault.GetDetail<XmlElement>();
var errorCode = faultDetails.GetElementsByTagName("errorCode")[0]?.InnerText;
var message = faultDetails.GetElementsByTagName("message")[0]?.InnerText;
```